# Descargar imagen de Picasso y almacenarla

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, picasso

Espero estén bien, quiero sacar una imagen de Picasso con la URL de la imagen, precisamente del storage de firebase para luego almacenarla en un arrayof.

Hasta el momento se descargarla y enviarla a un imageview.
Lo que intente día grabarla en una variable y castiar a tipo int, ya que arrayof almacena este tipo de datos pero no funcionó, utilizo lenguaje Kotlin.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Buenas Gastón, podrías poner el código donde te falla? Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, agrega el còdigo que realizas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podes hacer es obtener el bitmap que te trae esa url y luego enviarla donde quieras

En la documentación existe un metodo `onBitmapLoaded` que es un callback que te va a devolver el bitmap que trajo tu url

Documentación: https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/

Anda a la parte donde dice Target en ese link

```
Picasso.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .into(object : Target() {
                fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
                    /* Aca ya tenes el bitmap, podes setearlo a un imageview o guardarlo para enviarlo a otro lado */

                    //Seteamos la imagen al imageview
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }
            })
```